# spring-boot configure embeded server before async config

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I'm testing some functionality and I'd like to customize tomcat to enable JNDI and add one executor.

Then I'd like to configure spring's async with executor retrieved from tomcat's JNDI. Is it possible to do this without some "autoconfiguration" (or how to do it in spring without boot)?

when I debug code (in intellij) at first `customAsyncExecutor()` is executed and after that `tomcatFactory()`. I would like to call `tomcatFactory()` as first.

here is my code:

```
package com.github.bilak.poc.async;

import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

import javax.naming.NamingException;

import org.apache.catalina.Context;
import org.apache.catalina.Executor;
import org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat;
import org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.web.ContextResource;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.aop.interceptor.AsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerFactory;
import org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer;
import org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.AsyncConfigurerSupport;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.EnableAsync;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.EnableScheduling;
import org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.CustomizableThreadFactory;


@SpringBootApplication
@EnableScheduling
@EnableAsync
public class TomcatAsyncConfigurationPOCApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(TomcatAsyncConfigurationPOCApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Configuration
    public static class TomcatJNDIConfiguration {

        private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TomcatJNDIConfiguration.class);

        private final String asyncExecutorJNDIName;

        public TomcatJNDIConfiguration(@Value("${async.executor.jndi-name}") String asyncExecutorJNDIName) {
            this.asyncExecutorJNDIName = asyncExecutorJNDIName;
        }

        @Bean
        public EmbeddedServletContainerFactory tomcatFactory() {
            TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory tomcat = new TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory() {

                @Override
                protected TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer getTomcatEmbeddedServletContainer(Tomcat tomcat) {
                    tomcat.enableNaming();
                    return super.getTomcatEmbeddedServletContainer(tomcat);
                }

                @Override
                protected void postProcessContext(Context context) {
                    ContextResource resource = new ContextResource();
                    resource.setName("asyncThreadPoolExecutor");
                    resource.setType(Executor.class.getName());
                    resource.setProperty("namePrefix", "test");
                    resource.setProperty("maxThreads", "2");
                    context.getNamingResources().addResource(resource);
                }
            };

            return tomcat;
        }

        @Bean(name = "customAsyncExecutor")
        java.util.concurrent.Executor customAsyncExecutor() {
            JndiTemplate jndiTemplate = new JndiTemplate();
            java.util.concurrent.Executor executor;
            try {
                executor = (java.util.concurrent.Executor) jndiTemplate.lookup(asyncExecutorJNDIName);
            } catch (NamingException e) {
                logger.error("Unable to find async executor {} in jndi", asyncExecutorJNDIName, e);
                // TODO what will be the fallback when JNDI is not found?
                executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor(new CustomizableThreadFactory("ae-fallback"));
            }
            return executor;
        }

    }

    @Configuration
    public static class CustomAsyncConfigurerSupport extends AsyncConfigurerSupport {

        private java.util.concurrent.Executor customAsyncExecutor;

        public CustomAsyncConfigurerSupport(java.util.concurrent.Executor customAsyncExecutor) {
            this.customAsyncExecutor = customAsyncExecutor;
        }


        @Override
        public java.util.concurrent.Executor getAsyncExecutor() {
            return customAsyncExecutor;
        }

        @Override
        public AsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler getAsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler() {
            return null;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Why? why bother with JNDI when you are using an embedded tomcat... Seems like overkill.

Comment: I agree with the above comment.  However, you could add `EmbeddedServletContainerFactory tomcatFactory` as an argument to `customAsyncExecutor()` and that should force it to resolve `tomcatFactory` first.

Comment: that's just for testing purposes, I'd like to test some functionality using JNDI and I don't want to bother with xml configuration in standalone tomcat.